# Was all the fuel expended in each stage of a Saturn V launch?

Tags: apollo-program, saturn-v

Particularly the first and second stages into earth orbit - were the stages run dry before separation? On first thoughts, It would seem to be safer to do so, but I realised the engines required liquid fuel to act as a coolant prior to ignition in the combustion chamber.  Also, the final orbit might not be so precise if there's variation to the launch profile.

So, the question becomes: how much fuel was left in each stage?

I'd expect any excess fuel to be kept to a minimum since it is expensive (fuelwise) to lift unburnt fuel.

If answers can include the third stages and supply modules,   that'd be great.

Comment: No. There are questions on the site about this already. 10s of thousands of lbs were left in the first stage. It's more expensive to blow up your rocket by running the engines dry.

Comment: @OrganicMarble couldn't find such a question when searching - happy to be closed as a duplicate if you can find one

Comment: I'm not sure it's really a duplicate - and I can't find it yet either! Will report back.

Comment: I'm coming up, erm, dry! It may have been a discussion in comments.  You'll likely get an answer soon.

Comment: Related but not quite duplicate IMO: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21704/195

Comment: A good source is Apollo by the numbers, see [1](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4029/Apollo_18-23a_Launch_Vehicle_Propellant_Use.htm), [2](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4029/Apollo_18-23b_Launch_Vehicle_Propellant_Use.htm), [3](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4029/Apollo_18-23c_Launch_Vehicle_Propellant_Use.htm). You may write an answer yourself by using these tables.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Weren't the Saturn V launcher stages expendable? Why care if the engines melt from lack of coolant after the one use you will ever get out of them anyway?

Comment: I said nothing about engines melting, the issue is turbopumps exploding, and you don't want that to happen before you separate the stages. Read the answer.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Weren't the turbopumps expendable too?

Comment: Read the answer. It specifically addresses your concern.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Neither of the two answers say that the engines (or just the turbopumps) would need to be operational again after the burn.

Comment: @HenningMakholm no, of course not - the point is keeping them "operational" (read - "they, and the _rest of your rocket_, in one piece") until you have ditched them.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The big picture stage separation sequence for the Saturn was like this 1) Shut down first stage engines 2) Physically separate stages 3) ignite second stage engines.  If the booster exploded in step 1) it would have affected the mission negatively.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For the Saturn V, the first and second stages both cut off when a low-propellant-level sensor tripped in the tanks. Most launchers' booster stages do something similar -- burning to total depletion would be [dangerous for a number of reasons noted here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21705/195).

For the S-IC first stage, it wasn't unusual to leave 30 tons of propellant unconsumed, as [Apollo By The Numbers](https://georgetyson.com/files/apollostatistics.pdf) notes. This is a little more than 1% of the total stage tankage, and represents about 2 seconds of burn time.

For the S-II second stage, the residual propellant was usually 3-4 tons -- less than 1% of the initial amount, and again representing 2-3 seconds of burn time.

The orbital insertion burn on the S-IVB third stage, as with most orbital launchers, was cut off when the desired target velocity was reached. This allowed the stage to correct for off-nominal performance of the first and second stages -- it would do whatever it needed to do to get to the right altitude and speed.

Most of the fuel in the third stage was saved for the translunar burn, which was likewise stopped when the desired change in velocity was accomplished, again typically with 3-4 tons of fuel remaining, though that represents 10-15 seconds of burn time for the smaller, single-engine stage.

I believe all the other major burns on Apollo missions (course correction, lunar orbit insertion, etc) used velocity-based cutoffs as well.

Comment: 15 tons of propellant pr second! impressive!

Comment: From Apollo By The Numbers, overall program averages for the remaining fuel for the first three stages was, respectively, 1.50%, 0.82% & 8.42%

Comment: Fun fact: The Saturn V third stage engine could light three times. No third ignition was ever used in flight.

Comment: @Joshua - Actually the engine *was* ignited three times in Apollo 9 -- Once to put the CSM/LM stack into low earth orbit, and two for testing purposes. The second burn put the SIVB into an elliptical Earth orbit, and the third burn ejected the stage from the Earth-Moon system into Solar orbit. These burns were unusual in that they weren't pushing the CSM/LM, so they probably had quite a bit more acceleration than normal for an SIVB. http://klabs.org/history/history_docs/jsc_t/apollo_09_saturn_v.pdf

Comment: I thought I checked everything. :(

Answer (score 7):

I took the numbers from 'Apollo by the Numbers' and entered them into a spread sheet.

[image]

Still a lot of work to do with Apollo 9 to 17.

Any suggestions?

The left fuel is less than 3 % for stage 1 and 2 but less than 10 % for stage 3 final burn.

Comment: These [can be programmatically found](https://pastebin.com/42G68A68), although the data is a little dirty. I might fill in the table if I find the time. There is an interesting tidbit they provide with the Program Totals: For example, the total fuel consumption across all launches for fuel & oxidizer was: S1C: 1.50% SII: 0.82% SIVB 1st burn: 71.10% 2nd burn: 12.05%. In total just shy of 1 million lbs of propellant was left unused across all launches.